# How i can display in view the streaming Twitter GEM configured in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems, streaming

i try to display in rails view a streaming Twitter from Gem Twitter.

I configure my controller : welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
def index
require 'twitter'
client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
config.consumer_key        = "Hidden"
config.consumer_secret     = "Hidden"
config.access_token        = "Hidden"
config.access_token_secret = "Hidden"
end

client.sample do |object|
@tweets = object.text if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
end        
end
end
```

And my view like that : index.html.erb

```
<% @tweets.each do |element| %>
  <li><%= element %></li>
<% end %>
```

But nothing appear on my view.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tweetstream gem for it conflicts with the sferik/twitter gem. Worked for me.

**EDIT :** client.sample will respond with millions of tweets, probably overloading you server so I doubt you'll view will ever get rendered.